# Error compiling maven, spring: Invalid target release 13, when trying to upload project on heroku

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku, invalidation

I have a Spring project and I'm trying to upload it to heroku using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RHYDNSRSOs
But I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKqFA.png).
I tried to change the java.version in pom from 14 to 11 but still it dosen't work.
[Here is the java/maven version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGepw.png)
And here is the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.coronavirus</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CoronaVirus-tracker</name>
    <description>Corona-tracker</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>13</source>
                <target>13</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Heroku JDK version is 1.8. To install `14`, put `java.runtime.version=14` into your `system.properties` file as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions

Comment: Thank you very much